# Difference in performance using linear layout or constraint layout?

Tags: android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have worked on 2 apps and for me personally linear layouts are better as i can use weight sums and nested linear layouts which can set better layouts on different devices.

On applying weight sum i do not have worry about some differences  like changing sizes of layouts in xxhdpi, hdpi and stuff like that.On minor occasions i do changes in sizes of text boxes in hdpi , xhdpi.. but the point is they give better result and i have applied them where constraint layout were not fit to use.

The issue i hear about that using linear layouts you can have performance issues so applying constraint layouts are better.

So as experienced developers which ways are better when setting a layout of activity and what do you use in making apps?

Answer (score 0):

all depends upon your requirements, constraint layout is enhanced form of relative layout. in most cases constraint layout used to design responsive layouts but its code can be complex. on the other hand linear layout is easy to use. performance differences is hard to notice in most cases. for more information you can refer to this article

https://android.jlelse.eu/constraint-layout-performance-870e5f238100